# Error while trying to call JBPM process through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, persistence, jbpm, bpmn

This is what the error msg im getting When i try to run my Code.

```
     import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType;
 import org.kie.internal.KnowledgeBase;
  import org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
  import org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
  import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
  import org.kie.internal.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;

     public class ProcessMain {

       public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       // load up the knowledge base
           KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
          StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession =      kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    // start a new process instance

          ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello");

        ksession.insert(new Account()); 

       ksession.fireAllRules();

  }


      private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {
           KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder =           KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
           kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(
                  "simplerule.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);

         kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("sample.bpmn"),      ResourceType.BPMN2);
          if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
              throw new RuntimeException(kbuilder.getErrors()
        .toString());
          }
          KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
          kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
          return kbase;
      }
 }
```

This is my error

> 0    [main] WARN  bitronix.tm.Configuration  - cannot get this JVM
>   unique ID. Make sure it is configured and you only use ASCII
>   characters. Will        use IP address instead (unsafe for production
>   usage!).
>          778  [main] WARN  org.jbpm.services.task.HumanTaskConfigurator  - No        default interceptor found of type       org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor might be
>   mssing      jbpm-human-task-jpa module on classpath (error null
>            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No task persistence context available
>          at       org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskContext.getPersistenceContext(TaskContext.ja
>   va:114)
>         at        org.jbpm.services.task.commands.InitDeadlinesCommand.execute(InitDeadlinesCommand.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jbpm.services.task.commands.InitDeadlinesCommand.execute(InitDeadlinesComman
>   d.java:18)
>         at      org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl$SelfExecutionCommandServ
>   ice.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:65)   at
>   org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl.execute(TaskCommandExecu
>   torImpl.java:40)
>          at     org.jbpm.services.task.impl.TaskDeadlinesServiceImpl.initialize(TaskDeadlinesSer
>   viceImpl.java:367)
>          at          org.jbpm.services.task.HumanTaskConfigurator.getTaskService(HumanTaskConfigurato
>   r.java:153)
>           at       org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.factory.LocalTaskServiceFactory.newTaskService(Loc
>   alTaskServiceFactory.java:65)
>          at     org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SingletonRuntimeManager.init(SingletonRuntimeManag
>   er.java:82)
>          at      org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newSingletonRuntimeManag
>   er(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:71)
>          at com.sample.ProcessMain.createRuntimeManager(ProcessMain.java:63)
>         at com.sample.ProcessMain.main(ProcessMain.java:27)

Comment: It seems the code you pasted is not what you executed, as the stacktrace seems to indicate that your main operation is calling createRuntimeManager but I can't see that in the code you pasted?

Comment: Answer Kris (http://stackoverflow.com/users/221541/kris-verlaenen) if want your answer.